# What is the color palette/technique that has become so popular in TV shows?

Tags: film-techniques

I noticed that many recent TV shows have a color grading technique with bright candy-colors that pop out. For example, all of *[The Marvelous Mrs. Maisel](https://parade.com/977197/tinadonvito/marvelous-mrs-maisel-facts/)*, some of *Philip K. Dick's Electric Dreams* (e.g. "[Crazy Diamond](https://dansmediadigest.co.uk/philip-k-dicks-electric-dreams-crazy-diamond-78f99ead5a47)"), or *[The Good Place](https://filmdaily.co/news/the-good-place-best-episodes/)*. (Sample images linked.)

I don't remember seeing such color technique before about 5 years ago.

Is there a name for this technique?    Or is this just a mis-setting on the screen I am using?

I'll appreciate link to articles that discuss this. I have found articles that discuss a specific show, for example about the color palette in *Mrs. Maisel*, but none that discuss this as a phenomenon.

Comment: I have to say that Bryan Fuller's Pushing Daisy's comes to mind also and might be an earlier place to see where this bright "pop" aesthetic may have started as a trend. I don't remember who is the photographer/cinematographer on that series, but that may worth a look, which I will do when I get some time.

Comment: Do you have any stills or screenshots showing this effect?

Comment: I added links to sample images.

Comment: Why would this be a "phenomenon" when it is only used in a handful of shows? Considering that there are about 400 series produced each year in the US alone, we're talking about 1%.

Comment: I don't have any precise data, but of the shows I watched, a good fraction seem to have this  style. I do not recall seeing this  style at all before a few years ago.

Answer (score 3):

The technique of manipulating color is part of a process which is called "color grading".

I am not aware of a special name for this particular look. It's normal to see certain styles more often within a time period as film makers get inspired by other peoples' work. It's a trend, that probably subsides one day or shifts in another direction. However, it might also be influenced by increased mobile device streaming: If you're outside in bright sunlight you will benefit from poppy colors.

Comment: Thank you. So, that is the question: Does this look have a name, or even if not, where can I read about it? I supposed that everything has a name, or at least is discussed, by professionals in the field.

Comment: Thank you for the term "color grading." I have added it to the question